# Can Istio be deployed on a specific namespace instead of istio-system? How can Istio be used if there's only namespace access?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We only have namespace level access and was wondering how we could deploy Istio on a specific namespace which will be specific to applications deployed on that specific namespace. Is this a possibility?

I couldn't find any content online so was wondering if this has been tried out.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can. Easiest way to do that is using Helm chart: https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio.
Just specify needed namespace when doing 'helm install' and that's all.

Comment: Thanks @vasily! This was what I was looking for. I'm trying it out.